# How to detect if a file on a server has changed with Python/Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

This is a follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790699/how-to-download-pdf-files-with-python-scrapy-using-the-files-pipeline) question.

I want to download PDF files daily. So far my Scrapy code already works. Now I want to find out if the PDF files have changed.

**Does Scrapy have a built-in mechanism for this?** I couldn't find a hint in the documentation.

If not, I would download the respective PDF file and compare it with the previous day's PDF file using this model:

[Python library to detect if a file has changed between different runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912567/python-library-to-detect-if-a-file-has-changed-between-different-runs)

Comment: Check out this new open source monitoring tool [spidermon](https://spidermon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html]) Not tried though but I believe it will work in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You download the pdf for the first time and save it.
Next time you download it you calculate the [hash](https://www.pythoncentral.io/hashing-strings-with-python/) of the previous file and the new file. If both values are the same - there is no change in the file.